# Why Should $A = \{x | x^2 = 16\ \mbox{and}\ x+6=6\}$ Be An Empty Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the following set
$$A = \{x | x^2 = 16\ \mbox{and}\ x+6=6\}$$

From $x+6=6$ we know that $x$ is $0$, but the square of $0$ is not $16$ as $x^2 = 16$ says. Similarly, $\pm4+6 \neq 6$. Therefore we say that $A = \{\}$, or $A$ is a null set. We don't know what $x$ is because it is not properly defined, but why should this make $A$ a null set?

Comment: The set $A$ is defined as the set of those (and only those) numbers that satisfy **both** conditions; you said that there is **no** number that satisfy them both. So ...

Comment: As a side note, $A$ is not just *a* null set, i.e., one of possibly many different null sets; there exists exactly one null set and hence $A$ is **the** null set. Apart from this I prefer the name *empty* set .

Comment: The thing is someone told me whenever you have two values for $x$ from the two equations in this set-builder notation, you should know that the set is an empty set. But I was not thinking about "$x$ satisfying both the equations simultaneously", which is the right way to think of it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen By *a null set*, I meant $A$ belongs to the category of null sets just as we would say Tom is a cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x+6=6$, then $x=0$ and it's the only one solution... And $0^2\neq 16 $, hence the set $A$ is empty... Where's the problem? The $x$ in the set must satisfy **both** conditions, that is $x+6=6$ and $x^2=16$, but there are no such numbers.

Comment: I had thought about it before anyone answered, and therefore I don't think the question is appropriate. Anyway, can you confirm if the $x$ in $\{x|x=...\}$ is called range variable?

Answer (score 1):

An element in that set must satisfy both conditions. There are no elements that simultaneously satisfy both conditions. So there are no elements in the set.